# more link to display list of events in fullcalendar not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

```
$('#calendars').fullCalendar({ 
header: { left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month', center: 'title', right: 'prev,next' }, 
defaultDate: moment(deteDefault, "YYYY MM DD"), 
editable: false, 
ignoreTimezone: false, 
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events firstDay: firstDay.getfirstDay(), 
events: { url: $base_path, error: function() { $('#script-warning').show(); } } });
```

This is my code when events become more then it shows a link "+more" on full-calendar and on click over that shows other events. But in my case its not working in Mobile view as show in desktop view.If have any idea how this will work,please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be kind enough to paste all the relevant code here? Or create a jsfiddle that replicates the issue.

Comment: I meant, edit your question with all the relevant code - HTML, JS and jQuery

Comment: @sandeep s ,i have update my question. thanks.

Comment: Please read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question. We cannot help you if you are not able to describe the problem properly and with the appropriate example.